# How to remotely access Ubuntu Server via RDP through a web browser

Tags: linux, rdp, xrdp

While this isn’t required for what I’m doing. It would be pretty cool to achieve. Right now I can access my computer running Ubuntu Server remotely from any Windows PC via Xrdp.

I want to take this a step further by instead of having the client connect via the normal Remote Desktop app in Windows, I want to be able to connect through the web browser.

I know this is possible if the server is running Windows, but since this is a special case, is this possible?

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Control+a+computer+from+within+your+web+browser&l=1

Comment: @alexus Yeah I found that by doing a search and Java in the web browser has been discontinued for ten years now, so nice try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) is a free and open-source client-less remote desktop gateway that supports standard protocols like VNC, RDP, and SSH. It requires no plugins or client software; simply use an HTML5 web application such as a web browser.

There are a handful of other products that support browser access for a price too, like Zoho Assist, ThinLinc, Remote Access Plus, or even Microsoft's own [RDS web client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client-admin).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I saw Microsoft had one, but my server will be running linux, so that one is not exactly optimal

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no open source HTTP to RDP gateway. OTOH [noVNC](https://novnc.com/info.html) is very effective as a HTTP to VNC gateway (I [used this along with rdesktop](https://symcbean.blogspot.com/2020/04/covid19-provisioning-remote-access-with.html) to provide remote access to RDP desvices).

Do beware - there THOUSANDS of articles on the index about how to share a Linux session over VNC - the documentation for running a multi-head server is much more rare (and Google doesn't understand the difference).

Comment: Your answer was good too, but the first one was the closest to what I wanted, so I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use azure bastion if you have access to azure. Azure bastion is a PaaS service for remotely accessing servers using ssh or rdp. So no need to maintain the os and setup and configure a server

Comment: While that is cool, I would rather not rely on cloud services. I‘m that guy that would setup everything myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Chrome Remote Desktop?  https://remotedesktop.google.com/

Comment: I would like it to be through rdp so it can be through any web browser